# regex trim string and then append

Tags: regex

I don't now much about regex, but I'd like to trim a string that may end with an empty space (or may not) and then add an empty space at the end (in other words: if it ends with an empty space it's already ok, if it doesn't I want to append an empty space).

I've found to replace `\s*$` with an empty space, but with this if the string ends with an empty space, it adds two empty spaces (one for the empty space and one for the end of line).

How get I get it done?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I need to use that on an app (Macrodroid)..I don't know what it uses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your language/tool supports lookbehind, you can use:

- Find: `(?<=\S)$`
- Replace: `A SINGLE SPACE`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lFIRQ4/1/)

If it doesn't, use:

- Find: `\S$`
- Replace: `$0`  <-- there is a space after `$0`

Comment: Thanks, the second way works perfect!